# AsyncStorage not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

`console.log` returns undefined.
AsyncStorage doesn't work. It doesn't save and does not register.
Please help me.

```
if (this.props.zamqiDetay == 1) {
  this.setState({ number0State: this.props.processDetayDeger });
  AsyncStorage.setItem('loover', 'sadfasd');
}
```

Render:

```
render() {

  AsyncStorage.getItem('loover').then((value) => {
    this.setState({ loover: value });
  }).done();

  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
  console.log(this.state.loover);
  return ();
```

Comment: `AsyncStorage` is well async, `setState` is async. Do you expect to see immediate changes in state? How the first part of your code is related to `render` method? Also `render` method is not the right place to run side-effects (choose proper lifecycle method instead)

Comment: Never run `setState` in *render* since it re-triggers *render*

Comment: You need to move your getItem code outside of render, there is no reason it should be located there. Put it in a method where it makes more sense: componentDidMount for example ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
let storage = async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem('item');
storage().then((res)=>{
    if(res) {
      //we have out data
    }
}).catch((err)=>{
      // oops 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare await keyword while doing setItem and getItem in asynchronous storage

```
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('loover').then((value) => {
  this.setState({ loover: value });
}).done();

await AsyncStorage.setItem('loover', 'sadfasd');
```

Comment: `await` only works inside `async` functions. Do you propose to mark `render` method as `async`? If yes this would make it return a Promise not `ReactElement` expected by React.

Comment: Reread the question please, OP has async operation in `render` method. BTW it works with methods as well. But not with `render` because react infrastructure expects it to return a value, not a Promise